# Expand/Collapse Crosstab in CrystalReports for VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am attempting to recreate a CrossTab report in CrystalReports for VS2012 that was originally done using SSRS / ReportDesigner.

What I cannot figure out how to do is enable expand/collapse interactivity for the groupings at column or row level.

This type of behavior seems to be a fairly standard part of this type of report (other tools I am comparing all seem to have this behavior available).

How / where do I enable this behavior in my report definition in CrystalReports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot do this. Crystal reports provides very limited dynamic features. It is designed with the idea to print the report.

You can emulate similar behavior by placing 2 crosstabs in 2 on demand subreports ( one for expanded, one for collapsed crosstab)  However this looks like too much work to me and will require 2 calls to the database. If you already have the report in SSRS why would you convert it to Crystal ?

There are some other options to handle this: Check the first 3 minutes of this video:http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/Preview_Demo.aspx
It demonstrates the same data presented in SSRS matrix, Crystal crosstab and SQL Pivot table. The pivot table will allow your users to have expand/collapse functionality without reporting server available.

Comment: We've got some pretty serious delivery issues using SSRS and the client has simply stated that they want CrystalReports to be used, ostensibly because it will make the act of report creation a simple matter.  If only things were simple...

Comment: What kind of viewer they use to run the reports ? Crystal server or 3rd party ? To answer your other question: there is no difference between the VS and regular version for crosstabs.

Comment: Crystal server is the assumption although currently I am just working within VS and using preview.  The client's perspective is that they would like to view and interact with their reports primarily through the browser and within the context of their ASP.NET MVC web application.  This need is where the delivery issues start to become a problem with SSRS/MS ReportViewer.

Comment: Then you will be restricted to the options provided by Crystal reports. The tool I mentioned is a Desktop application and will not work for you. I guess you are trying to run the SSRS report in Crystal server, is this correct ?

Comment: That's an interesting comment you've made -- does CrystalServer support delivery / viewing of SSRS reports (i.e. RDL reports)?  That might help us get around the problems we are having using the MS ReportViewer.

Comment: I never actually used this, but it was mentioned in multiple places that Crystal server is able to run SSRS 

If you have existing Microsoft Reporting Services reports you can avoid a costly migration by referencing them within SAP Crystal Reports Server to present a single reporting UI to business users, regardless of the reporting server used.

http://crystalreports.com/products/sap-crystal-reports-server.asp

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports' cross-tab objects don't support expanding or collapsing.  Nor do they support drill-down functionality.

Comment: in your experience is this true only for the VS version or would that statement apply to CrossTab type reporting across all of CR offerings?  I ask only because the VS version is free and this might be the type of feature leveraged to entice someone to buy (and because I am foolishly hopeful).

Comment: It's true in ever edition that I've used (v4->v2008), embedding in VS or not.